# What is the name of the "\\?\" construct in windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, explorer

I had to help someone delete a folder that had weird characters in it that caused the path to be re-interepeted as a different path:

```
c:\test.     -> c:\test
```

It took me a while to recall the `\\?\` construct, since I have no idea what it's called or how to search for it. Once I remembered it, though, it was easy:

```
\\?\c:\test. -> c:\test.
```

What is the name of this construct, that I (and others) may search for it?

Comment: It is the native pathname.  Not that this will help you, nobody else knows what it is called.  Just ask the question.

Comment: I think I've seen it referred to as a *symbolic link prefix* but I can't find a reference right now.

Comment: I call it the _double-back-slash-and-question-mark-thing_. People that know it understand me.

Comment: @HansPassant it sounds to me like he wants to know what it's called so he can search for it and thus avoid asking duplicate questions...?

Comment: Hmm, a question that leaves visitors guessing why it is being asked is never a very good one.

Comment: @HansPassant I stated why I cared in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it has an official name in widespread use, so I doubt that you'll get very far in any searches. It is described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx#maxpath

> The Windows API has many functions that also have Unicode versions to permit an extended-length path for a maximum total path length of 32,767 characters. This type of path is composed of components separated by backslashes, each up to the value returned in the lpMaximumComponentLength parameter of the GetVolumeInformation function (this value is commonly 255 characters). To specify an extended-length path, use the "\\?\" prefix. For example, "\\?\D:\very long path".

For this usage it might be called the *extended-length path prefix*. However the prefix serves other purposes, most specifically suppressing user mode path canonicalisation, the purpose that you were availing yourself of.

As you can see from comments to this answer, there are lots of varied opinions on the most suitable name. I think that we can all agree that there is no single officially used name for this thing!

Comment: Interesting. At best, you might call it some variety of namespace (as in the \\.\ device namespace), but that's good enough.

Comment: If you call `ntdll!RtlDosPathNameToNtPathName_U`, the translated `UNICODE_STRING` will use the `\??` native prefix for DOS devices, so I call it the Win32 DOS Device prefix. Note that if you have access to the `\\?\GlobalRoot` link, then `\\?\ ` actually opens up the entire native namespace, including the `\Sessions` directory.

Comment: @eryksun: Note the difference between `\\?\ ` and `\??\ `

Comment: @David: Allowing extended-length paths is a reason to use it, but that isn't its function.  Its function is to bypass the user-mode path canonicalization and forward the path directly to the file-handling syscalls.  Overcoming the limitations of that canonicalization code is a consequence of that bypass.

Comment: @BenVoigt, what do you mean? `\??` is the prefix for DOS devices used in native NT code, to which Win32 calls will translate `\\?\ `. Note that `\??` is sessionized. In addition to `\Global??` DOS devices, it also accesses logon session device links from `\Sessions\0\DosDevices\LOGONID`, where for example your session network and subst drives are created. `DefineDosDevice` only creates global devices when run as LocalSystem, which is easy enough to check with Sysinternals `psexec -s cmd /c subst W: C:\Windows` (runs as LocalSystem) and then `accesschk -qo \Global??\W:`.

Comment: @eryksun: Oh I see, you aren't saying it is the DOS device prefix, you're saying it is the prefix used by Win32 code to generate the DOS device prefix.

Comment: @BenVoigt, per @MatteoItalia perhaps a better name is "Raw Win32 File Namespace", since path canonicalization is bypassed (e.g. translating slash to backslash). Also, `RtlDetermineDosPathNameType_U` returns the same type for `\\.\ ` and `\\?\ ` paths, which ReactOS calls ([link](http://svn.reactos.org/svn/reactos/tags/ReactOS-0.3.17/reactos/lib/rtl/path.c?view=markup#l1327)) `RtlPathTypeLocalDevice` ([link](http://svn.reactos.org/svn/reactos/tags/ReactOS-0.3.17/reactos/include/psdk/winternl.h?view=markup#l874)), and `RtlDosPathNameToNtPathName_U` translates them the same.